# addressing Console tab in "Inspect Element" of a page in iMacro Firefox

Tags: javascript, instagram, imacros

I just find a javascript code that if you paste it in the "Console" tab in the Inspect Element of the Instagram page, it would cancel a group of pending follow requests.

Since there are about thousands of pending follow-requests, I want to use the iMacro to ease the canceling procedure.

I use iMacro to record the canceling process (go to page,copy the code, bringing the inspect element up,go to Console tab,and paste the code into it,and run!)

but here is the problem: **when I play that, it can not bring the Inspect Element mode of the browser (and Console tab) to run the next steps.**

I wonder if anyone knows how can I address it in the iMacro??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have a Thread on the iMacros Forum from a few years ago about calling 'Ctrl^Shift^J' or 'Ctrl^Shift^K' with the 'EVENT' Mode, well..., depending on your FCI... + What you "do" in the Console should also work from a '.js' Script, the 'URL GOTO=javascript' Syntax, and/or a pure JS Bookmarklet...

Comment: well, I don't get what you mean. could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Yeah, well, not complicated to type 1 Word ("console") in the Searchbox on the iMacros Forum, I would think...:
https://forum.imacros.net/search.php?keywords=console&terms=all&author=chivracq&sc=1&sf=all&sr=topics&sk=t&sd=d&st=0&ch=300&t=0&submit=Search
=> You'll have 2 Threads interesting for you, from 2017, from a quick look, and probably a few more also..., I didn't check them all... But the one I meant is called "Message without stopping macro?"...